SwiftUI Image unable to load localized image from Assets.xcassets
The following code will load non-localized version of image, even I am running in a Chinese localized environment.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Image("xxx")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 100)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Load wrong image


I need to fix the code by using UIKit to load the image.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private func localizedImage(_ named: String) -> Image {
         if let uiImage = UIImage(named: named) {
             return Image(uiImage: uiImage)
         }
         return Image(named) // fallback
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            localizedImage("xxx")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 100)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Correct localized image loaded


I was wondering, why SwiftUI Image behave such a way?
